# ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager returns user without including related objects (Lazy Loading)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a custom user class `User` derived from `IdentityUser`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public UserInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

I have used a `UserInfo` class and two subclasses to store additional user info based on the user type:

```
public class UserInfo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; } = false;
}

public class StudentInfo : UserInfo 
{
    public List<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class InstructorInfo : UserInfo
{
   public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Account()` action of `UsersController`, I have used the injected `UserManager` instance to get the user from the user store:

```
public class UsersController 
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> usrMgr;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleMgr;

    public UsersController(UserManager<User> usrMgr, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleMgr) 
     => (this.usrMgr, this.roleMgr) = (usrMgr, roleMgr);

    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Account()
    {
        User user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User); // Here user.Info is null
        return user is null ? NotFound() : View(user);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `GetUserAsync(this.User)` method does not include the `UserInfo` property but keeps it as `null`.  `FindByIdAsync(userId)` does not include it either. If this was a `DbContext`, I could've used an `.Include()` but I'm not quite sure how to tell the `UserManager` to include the related properties here.

Comment: you have a custom `User`, so you should create a custom `UserManager` as well, with that you can override the method `GetUserAsync` to include your extended info. Otherwise (not creating any custom `UserManager`), you need to consume the DbContext directly.

Comment: King King is correct. The user manager you are using is based on `IdentityUser` not your `User` deriving from `IdentityUser`, thus it knows nothing about `UserInfo`. Alternatively to overriding user manager methods, you can access property [`Users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.users?view=aspnetcore-5.0) being `IQueryable` of users and execute database query directly on it. Advantage of such approach is that you can easily chain `Include()` to it and thanks to that load `UserInfo`.

Comment: @KingKing Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't know that `UserManager` must be extended too, never came across such a scenario before.

Comment: @Prolog I really like the idea of using `UserManager.Users`. This is what I'm using now: `await userManager.Users.Include(usr => usr.UserInfo).FirstOrDefaultAsync(usr => usr.Id == userManager.GetUserId(this.User));` Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8065832/prolog), the `UserManager` has a  `UserManager.Users` property which is an `IQueryable<TUser>`.  Therefore, the `Include()` method can be chained to it just like any other `IQueryable<T>`:

```
await userManager
    .Users
    .Include(usr => usr.UserInfo)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(usr => usr.Id == userManager.GetUserId(this.User));
```

An alternative solution as suggested by [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king), is creating a custom `UserManager`.